# When should you remove outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, outlier

Let's say I've found some outliers in a column in my dataset and have decided to remove them.

Should I do this before or after I split the dataset into train/test sets?

Comment: Why would you remove the outliers?

Comment: We want our models to model the general trend of something. Perhaps the outliers skew the trend in one way or another and make the models less performant?

Answer (score 2):

If you decided to remove outliers. **Please remove them before the split**(even not only before a split, it's better to do the entire analysis(stat-testing, visualization) again after removing them, you may find interesting things by doing this).

If you remove outliers in only any one of train/test set it will create more problems.
(EX: An outlier in train set may not be an outlier in combined/full set, also the model will have high variance if you do so)

Comment: @vekatesh U are right absolutely. One should always wipe features in prior if it founds.

Comment: I disagree with @venkatesh, actually in order to prevent any form of leakage the first thing you have to do is splitting between train and test. Test is something you should not be able to see until the very last moment, if you remove outliers before splitting you are contaminating the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think two case is not different too much. (Eventually the all outlier is deleted)

But the proportion of the train/test set(e.x : 7:3) may different if you remove the outlier after the split.

So I recommend remove outlier before split if you could.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @rusiano. If you remove outliers before split, you are affecting test/validation data. Test data should be unspoiled.

Regarding @VenkateshGandi answer: "If you remove outliers in only any one of train/test set it will create more problems.". In this case, don't remove outliers. Removing outliers is not always useful.

Comment: Welcome @HD2000! Would you be able to provide a reference or source to look into for further reading on this? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).